# Building ROC curve from scrach using Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, roc

I'm trying to build ROC curve from scratch using Matlab. When i run the file
auc is

```
auc_area =

-2.8129e-006
```

I think it mises the cut off step but i cant understand it. is there any function to perform it?
this is my code:

```
num_pos = sum(all_labels);
tp = cumsum(l==1,1);
fp = repmat((1:n)',[1 m])-tp;

num_neg = n-num_pos;
fpr = bsxfun(@rdivide,fp,num_neg); %False Positive Rate
tpr = bsxfun(@rdivide,tp,num_pos); %True Positive Rate

%Plot the ROC curve

plot(fpr,tpr);
xlabel('False Positive');
ylabel('True Positive');

auc_area = sum(tpr.*[(diff(fp)==1); zeros(1,m)])./num_neg;
```

Comment: Can you post a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a small amount of sample data? You are missing some pieces, but it's hard to point to them without a working example. Mostly I want to know what is in `l`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that do that. I wrote it a 3 years ago.

```
function auc = areaundercurve(FPR,TPR)
% given true positive rate and false positive rate calculates the area under the curve
% true positive are on the y-axis and false positives on the x-axis
% sum rectangular area between all points
% example: auc=areaundercurve(FPR,TPR);
[x2,inds]=sort(FPR);
x2=[x2,1]; % the trick is in inventing a last point 1,1
y2=TPR(inds);
y2=[y2,1];
xdiff=diff(x2);
xdiff=[x2(1),xdiff];
auc1=sum(y2.*xdiff); % upper point area
auc2=sum([0,y2([1:end-1])].*xdiff); % lower point area
auc=mean([auc1,auc2]);
end
```